# "winning-configuration-property" algorithm : spring configuration properties run time determination based on application specific qualifiers

Tags: configuration-files, spring-cloud-config

I need to implement a "winning-configuration-property" algorithm in my application.

For example:

```
for property: dashboard_material
```

i would create a file (I am planning to represent each property as a file. This is slightly negotiable)dashboard_material.yml , with the following value
(which format i believe presents a consolidated view of the variants of the property and is more suitable for impact analysis when someone changes values in a  particular scenario) :

```
car_type=luxury&car_subtype=luxury_sedan&special_features=none              : leather
car_type=luxury&car_subtype=luxury_sedan&special_features=limited_edition   : premium_leather
car_type=economy                                                            : pseudo_leather
default                                                                     : pseudo_leather
```

I need the closest match. A luxury car can be a sedan or a compact.
I am assuming these are "decorators" of a car in object oriented terms, but not finding any useful implementation for the above problem from sample decorator patterns.

For example an API:

GET /configurations/dashboard_material should return the following values based on input parameters:

```
car_type=economy                                : pseudo_leather
car_type=luxury & car_subtype=luxury_sedan      : leather
car_type=luxury                                 : pseudo_leather (from default. Error or null if value does not exist)
```

This looks very similiar to the "specifications" or "queryDSL" problem with GetAPIs - in terms of slicing and dicing based on criteria.
but basically i am looking for a run-time determination of a config value from a single microservice
(which is a spring config client. I use git2consul to push values from git into consul KV. The spring config client is tied into the consul KV. I am open to any equivalent or better alternatives).

I would ideally like to do all the processing as a post-processing after the configuration is read (from either a spring config server or consul KV),
so that no real processing happens after the query is recieved. The same post processing  will also have to happen after every spring config client "refresh" interval based
on configuration property updates.

I have previously seen such an implementation (as an ops engineer) with netflix archaius implementation, but not again finding any suitable text on the archaius pages.

My trivial/naive solution would be to create multiple maps/trees to store the data and then consolidate them into a single map based on the API request effectively overriding some of the values from the lower priority maps.

I am looking for any open-source implementations or references and avoid having to create new code.